# Global variables as Functions in JEB

Tags: ghidra, jeb

I was using Ghidra trying decompile a .sys driver. Kinda newbie, but getting some help.
I see decompiler outputs a lot of "artifacts" (code weird or hard to understand). At least I have renamed some functions after see the functionality of them. Because at some point I was unable to get rid of many of those artifacts (usually by adjusting the right types in some variables) I decided to try another de-compiler: JEB Community Edition (from PNF Software).
It seems that it outputs better de-compiled code than Ghidra, it detects a lot more types tha Ghidra too, but the now I hit the wall with the following.
In Ghidra I have a function that I renamed like this:

```
int FUN_10001ea0(void)

{
  EnumerateAndProcessPCIDevices(ProcessMatchingPCIDevice);
  return 0;
}
```

ProcessMatchingPCIDevice (also renamed) seems to be a function too, because I double click that and it send me to the function. However, in JEB decompilation result is not the case. Look:

```
int sub_10001EA0() {
    sub_10001A40(&gvar_10001E10);
    return 0;
}
```

For some reason it just detects it as a global variable. Double click but it only shows declaration in Disassembly.

Is there any missing analysis or functionality in JEB that Ghidra does have?

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE. `gvar_` merely sounds like something that a tool would prepend to names of global variables. Given it's a variable, it's not local and there is only the address as additional context, this seems sensible. I don't think there's much more to it, really. Otherwise I may have misunderstood what you're asking. Side-note: it would probably have been better to show the original output from Ghidra (before your changes) for comparison.

Comment: I don't have the original input (or the original de-compilation) anymore in Ghidra, but it was something like this:

`int FUN_10001ea0(void)

{
  FUN_10001A40(INT_10001e10);
  return 0;
}
`

Comment: @0xC0000022L Perhaps I didn't ask properly. In Ghidra I can simply navigate to the function used as a parameter, perhaps because it seems that is a pointer to function. JEB doesn't seem to do recognize that or I simply don't know how to do it

Comment: Wait, so you're saying `ProcessMatchingPCIDevice` is a function in your case? Yeah, I didn't understand it like that so far.

Comment: @0xC0000022L In Ghidra detects it like a function, but not in JEB. I don't understand why.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a Chinese, what is JEB? I know `Global variables`  and `function`.

Comment: @Tom JEB Decompiler is a product from PNF Software.

Comment: @Mr_LinDowsMac Thank you for your explain, I don't know about JEB.